Do we want a disclaimer on the sidebar that we cannot offer medical advice?
Another Stack Exchange Site, judaism.stackexchange.com has the following disclaimer on right side nav for new users:


Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information you find here as if it came from a crowd of your friends.

Do we want such a disclaimer for our site to warn that we can't offer medical advice? If so, what should it say?

"Cogsci.SE does not offer medical advice, medical assistance, loan deferment, free wifi, bagels without creamcheese..." if we list everything we don't do we'll be here all damn day and do absolutely nothing to help our users nor will we actually protect the site legally.

I would say no. We've already decided we're not doing strictly self-help questions, such disclaimers are ugly, discouraging legalese. Unless someone can prove it's a potential problem beyond typical lawyer double talk I side strongly against any extra inclusion of legalese anywhere outside of the Legal page.

where is ... the legal tab?

Oh wow, it's entirely at the bottom. Oh well, I agree. At least it's there.

@StevenJeuris it's at the bottom, all but invisible. Where it belongs.

That doesn't make it a 'tab' really does it? :) Better update your answer and link to the 'legal page'. ;p
